# advantage of using recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

After reading through the documentation, i understand that recaptcha makes it difficult for the bots to do a form submission. This reduces spam for sure.

Apart from this, is there other advantage of using recaptcha?

Some articles were indicating that from a proxy or a virtual machine(for the first time), recaptcha is triggered. But is this really needed or rather what is the advantage of this?

Also, whether recaptcha does something to prevent bots crawling the website? I do not think that might be a case because this may affect search engine crawlers also.

From the documentation, "reCAPTCHA protects you against spam and other types of automated abuse." what are the other  types of automated abuses in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't matter if the bot is friendly or malicious. Some webmasters don't want bots on their website, and some bots do not respect robot.txt that would tell the bots to keep off their lawn. Besides, web crawlers should not be on the pages that require the user to post information about themselves.

To quote the website, "reCAPTCHA offers more than just spam protection. Every time our CAPTCHAs are solved, that human effort helps digitize text, annotate images, and build machine learning datasets. This in turn helps preserve books, improve maps, and solve hard AI problems."